# Getting GIS experience if no companies hire entry level

Tags: career

I graduated with a BS in Geography with a Business/GIS Minor, ever since I graduated I wanted to get into GIS. The GIS classes I took in college really interested me, but after 2 years of applying to GIS jobs and not getting one interview I am starting to think I may just have to work for $10 an hour and live with mom and dad the rest of my life.

It's incredibly frustrating working dead end jobs because I can't get my foot in the door with the career that I want. Every application is the same story, not enough experience.....how in the world am I supposed to get experience if no companies hire entry level?

I have tried to do my own work at home but I can't afford to just buy esris software.

Answer (score 1):

I got my current job as a summer student for a municipality - check out those local to you.
It's not the most interesting and stimulating but it'll help you get experience and your foot in the door!

Maybe build a GIS portfolio online, see if you can take additional classes and get a certification - that counts as experience.